# Google Toolkit API Settings Save not working

Tags: google-identity-toolkit, google-api-console

On the Identity Toolkit API Settings page on Google API Console I have provided all the URLs and Rollout %. I see the client and server configuration snippets and the blue Save button. No errors reported. Click Save. It goes to Saving... for a second and returns. Nothing is saved. Go back and revisit - everything is empty. Correspondingly I see the error when trying to execute the toolkit as well with CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had the same issue yesterday evening. Retried this morning ... works again. Looks like it was just a temporary downtime.

Hope it is solved for you also.

Comment: Yes it does. Was down for a few days. Thank you for the note.